# Problem installing GeoIP on my NetHunter with pip 23.3 an python 3.11.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I am going to install the GeoIP package I have this problem

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'GeoIP' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -mbranch-protection=standard -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c py_GeoIP.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/py_GeoIP.o
      py_GeoIP.c:23:10: fatal error: GeoIP.h: No such file or directory
         23 | #include "GeoIP.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for GeoIP
  Running setup.py clean for GeoIP
Failed to build GeoIP
ERROR: Could not build wheels for GeoIP, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install the GeoIP on my no rooted NetHunter phone and I get an error.
My requirements:

- pip 23.3
- python 3.11.6

Comment: Which GeoIP? [This one?](https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/) It hasn't been updated in nearly 10 years so it seems it's probably not compatible with modern Python packaging infrastructure and libraries. The simple fix is to find a maintained library with the same basic features.

Comment: [**Requirements:** Python 2.5+ or 3.3+, GeoIP C Library 1.4.7 or greater](https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/) — Have you installed the GeoIP C library…?

Comment: It also looks like the underlying C library depenends on a removed API and has been Deprecated itself, see https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c so there is no use in trying to get this python package to work

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of GeoIP (version 1.3.2) was released on Aug 22, 2014. That's about 10 years ago. I honestly do not think it will be compatible to your python 3.11.6.

Even if it works, IMO it's not a good idea to use packages that seems to be abandoned moreso a package that hasn't been maintained for nearly a decade. You may want to visit https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/.